# How to change HTML content with Flask and Nginx on Droplet Digital Ocean?

Tags: python, nginx, post, flask

Basically I have followed step by step this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04, and right now I can see my website www.XXX.com perfectly with the text "Hello There".

The first issue is that no matter how much I change the file that "return", I will always see the text "Hello There". I tried also restarting nginx many times, but it doesn't work.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    #line that I usually try to edit, but nothing happens...
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Furthermore the tutorial doesn't explain where to have the folders "static" and "template" in order to have them communicating by Flask. I have read so much about changing nginx conf file and/or redirecting, it is almost a week I am trying every tutorial I see, but nothing works so far.

How can I make the html changing? Where should I write an index.html so that Flask can actually see it and "index.html" can do POST request to it? In localhost everything looks different, since there is templates folder. But here it doesn't seem to care.

Thanks!

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, I changed the return to `return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There, general Kenobi!</h1>"` and started the server. Everything works, I see the new text. I'm not sure I understood your problem. Are you sure you enter on `localhost:5000/` to test it?

Comment: You have to reload / restart uwsgi instead of nginx when you change the code.

Comment: I do not use localhost by my domain, so  www.mydomain.com shows me "Hello There!", and no matter how many changes I do on flask. The message is always the same. When I am in localhost I can see the change as well. I am considering a nginx-override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uWSGI does not reload the python code by default. You have to either manually restart or reload uWSGI when you change code, or configure uWSGI to auto reload. uWSGI has many configuration options that you can use.

For development you can use the `--python-autoreload` option. This will reload every time code changes, similar to django runserver. There's a performance cost for this option, so it should not be used in production. Options can be command line flags or included in the uwsgi config file.

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
python-autoreload = true
...
```

In production there are many other ways to reload the app. The simplest might be to just send a `SIGHUP` signal to the uwsgi process. For example using the linux command `pkill`

```
pkill --signal SIGHUP uwsgi
```

Another option is to use `touch-reload`. That will only watch a single file for changes and reload uWSGI if the file is modified. So this can be used in production without much overhead.

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
touch-reload = /tmp/somefile
...
```

Use the command `touch /tmp/somefile` to update the file timestamp.

Several other ways to configure reloading are described in this section of the uWSGI docs: [The Art of Graceful Reloading](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I think am understanding more the issue. I am in production and according to what you wrote I changed the    myproject.ini with touch-reload = /myproject/myproject.py. But nothing changes sadly. PS: Is your link broken?

Comment: You have to restart the uwsgi master process after changing the config file. I've fixed the link. Thanks for checking that.

Comment: You saved my day! Fame and happiness on you! :D

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers